Bad Gateway when creating Logic Apps to on-prem SQL connection via Gateway
Testing the Azure on-premises Data Gateway with a local SQL DB instance.
When trying to create a 'SQL Server Get Rows (v2)' connector inside a Logic App with the below details, I get the following error;
Connector config

Failed to create connection: { "error": { "code": 502, "source": "logic-apis-northeurope.azure-apim.net", "clientRequestId": "3d5d9276-c103-4830-abdb-7687cc6a9d4f", "message": "BadGateway",
"innerError": { "status": 502, "message": "Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - TCP Provider: )

The steps I took to setup this process are as below;

Local SQL Server Express instance created on my laptop
Installed Azure On-premises Data Gateway
Setup new Resource Group with Data Gateway, connection and Logic App
Connection finds the Gateway under my subscription, (my device is being identified on the Power Platform so I know it can see the laptop through the Gateway)
Created logic App flow to connect to the on-premise SQL Server database

I can't fathom if this is a firewall issue on my laptop, or a SQL config I need to allow for?

Localdb might be a bit too local, isn't it per user? Not sure it will be visible

When I say local, I just mean its a DB installed on my laptops SQL server instance
Was initially following this youtube guide, seems to be ok on here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jK0iXIU5PMw&t=475s

Resolved - I'm not sure what it was, but I added the TCP 1433 outbound and inbound to my firewall and recreated the sql user profile, and it suddenly started working
